# How to capture the correct datetime value from Active Directory into a variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to capture a datetime field from Active Directory into a variable of datetime datatype. When I tried the below it gives me always gives me a value of '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' even when the attribute is NULL or has a value.

```
objResult = objSearch.FindOne()    
Dim testdate as DateTime = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("pwdFailureTime").Value
```

I have been playing around with the syntax, but using a string datatype throws an exception. Please help.

Comment: What value is in `objResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("pwdFailureTime").Value`? Where do you see it? Can you confirm the code is not reading the time (and that it's not 0 as you found)?

Comment: What about `Dim testdate as DateTime = DateTime.parseExact(objResult.GetDirecftoryEntry().Properties(""pwdFailureTime").Value.ToString(), "yyyyMMddHHmmssZ", Nothing)`?  Please, lookup the right format string.

Comment: There is today's date time stored in the Active Directory against the "pwdFailureTime" attribute (05/16/2017 11:32:53 AM). I want this value to be stored in a variable.